# Why is my test failing to detect that button will enable when form fields are not empty?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I have implemented a login page such that when emailId and password fields are empty it keeps the button disabled and enable the button once both fields are filled with some text.

Here is my code:

Login.tsx:

```
const Login = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const [emailId, setEmailId] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    return (
        <>
            <NavBar variant="secondary" button={<SignupBtn />} />
            <Container>
                <MuiTextField
                    fullWidth
                    label="Email address"
                    id="outlined-size-small"
                    size="small"
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        setEmailId(event.target.value);
                        setError("");
                    }}
                />
                <MuiTextField
                    fullWidth
                    label="Password"
                    id="outlined-size-small"
                    size="small"
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        setPassword(event.target.value);
                        setError("");
                    }}
                />
                {error && (
                    <Alert variant="outlined" severity="error">
                        {error}
                    </Alert>
                )}
                <Button variant="contained" disabled={!emailId || !password} onClick={(e) => handleLogin({ e, navigate, data: { emailId, password }, setError, setLoading })}>
                    {loading ? <Progress size={20} /> : "Login"}
                </Button>
            </Container>
        </>
    );
};
```

Here is my test code:

```
test("button enables when form fields are not empty", async () => {
  
render(<Login />, { wrapper: BrowserRouter });
  
const user = userEvent.setup();
  
const emailTextField = screen.getByLabelText(/email address/i); 
const passwordTextField = screen.getByLabelText(/password/i); 
const LoginBtn = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Login" });
  
await waitFor(async () => {
  
   await user.type(emailTextField, "hello");  
   await user.type(passwordTextField, "12345");
   expect(LoginBtn).toBeEnabled();  
  });
});
```

On running the above test logic I get an error as:

```
 Received element is not enabled:
    expect(LoginBtn).toBeEnabled();
                     ^
```

I am trying to learn to test. Please guide me on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is the `LoginBtn` variable referencing the correct element? Can you run a debug after typing the email and password?

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. Can you post the code using stackblitz or codesandbox?

Comment: @Lin Du, I have reproduced the issue you can check the code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-meninsky-11z917?file=/src/Login.test.tsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should set a different `id` to each `TextField` component. It's important. It will set the relationship between the `label` and `input` elements like the below:

```
<label for="username-input">Username</label>
<input id="username-input" />
```

So that you can query the `input` node correctly using `screen.getByLabelText('Username')`.

From the documentation of [`TextField`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/#props), we know:

> `id`: The `id` of the input element. Use this prop to make `label` and `helperText` accessible for screen readers.

2. You don't need to use `waitFor`.

E.g.

`Login.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TextField, Button } from "@mui/material";
import "./styles.css";

export default function Login() {
  const [emailId, setEmailId] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField
        label="Email address"
        id="email"
        onChange={(event) => setEmailId(event.target.value)}
      />
      <TextField
        label="Password"
        id="pwd"
        onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
      />

      <Button variant="contained" disabled={!emailId || !password}>
        Login
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Login.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import Login from "./Login";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

test("button enabling and disabling based on textfield", async () => {
  render(<Login />);
  const user = userEvent.setup({ document });
  const emailTextField = screen.getByLabelText(/email address/i);
  const passwordTextField = screen.getByLabelText(/password/i);
  const LoginBtn = screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Login" });

  await user.type(emailTextField, "hello");
  await user.type(passwordTextField, "12345");
  expect(LoginBtn).toBeEnabled();
});
```

package versions:

```json
@mui/material: ^5.11.0
@testing-library/user-event: ^14.4.3
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-75169372-b5qf5d?file=/src/Login.test.tsx)